# Glassfish 4 Admin not running from Netbeans 7.4 (Password Incorrect)

Tags: netbeans-7, glassfish-4

I am trying to run Glassfish 4 using Netbeans 7.4 IDE, but I am receiving an error dialog like

```
Please check server admin user name and password properties.

Also please check the server log file for other possible causes.
```

I am passing the correct user name and password, I have ensured the same by running the glassfish 4 from the windows command prompt, it is running properly, but it is not running from Netbeans 7.4

Server log also attached for your reference.

```
[2013-08-21T21:09:02.736+0530] [glassfish 4.0] [INFO] [NCLS-LOGGING-00009] [javax.enterprise.logging] [tid: _ThreadID=1 _ThreadName=main] [timeMillis: 1377099542736] [levelValue: 800] [[
  Running GlassFish Version: GlassFish Server Open Source Edition  4.0  (build 89)]]

[2013-08-21T21:09:02.740+0530] [glassfish 4.0] [INFO] [NCLS-LOGGING-00010] [javax.enterprise.logging] [tid: _ThreadID=1 _ThreadName=main] [timeMillis: 1377099542740] [levelValue: 800] [[
  Server log file is using Formatter class: com.sun.enterprise.server.logging.ODLLogFormatter]]

[2013-08-21T21:09:02.923+0530] [glassfish 4.0] [INFO] [realm.loaded.successfully] [javax.enterprise.system.core.security.com.sun.enterprise.security.auth.realm] [tid: _ThreadID=1 _ThreadName=main] [timeMillis: 1377099542923] [levelValue: 800] [[
  SEC1115: Realm [admin-realm] of classtype [com.sun.enterprise.security.auth.realm.file.FileRealm] successfully created.]]

[2013-08-21T21:09:02.928+0530] [glassfish 4.0] [INFO] [realm.loaded.successfully] [javax.enterprise.system.core.security.com.sun.enterprise.security.auth.realm] [tid: _ThreadID=1 _ThreadName=main] [timeMillis: 1377099542928] [levelValue: 800] [[
  SEC1115: Realm [file] of classtype [com.sun.enterprise.security.auth.realm.file.FileRealm] successfully created.]]

[2013-08-21T21:09:02.935+0530] [glassfish 4.0] [INFO] [realm.loaded.successfully] [javax.enterprise.system.core.security.com.sun.enterprise.security.auth.realm] [tid: _ThreadID=1 _ThreadName=main] [timeMillis: 1377099542935] [levelValue: 800] [[
  SEC1115: Realm [certificate] of classtype [com.sun.enterprise.security.auth.realm.certificate.CertificateRealm] successfully created.]]

[2013-08-21T21:09:03.466+0530] [glassfish 4.0] [INFO] [] [javax.enterprise.system.core] [tid: _ThreadID=1 _ThreadName=main] [timeMillis: 1377099543466] [levelValue: 800] [[
  Grizzly Framework 2.3.1 started in: 25ms - bound to [/0.0.0.0:8,080]]]

[2013-08-21T21:09:03.503+0530] [glassfish 4.0] [INFO] [] [javax.enterprise.system.core] [tid: _ThreadID=1 _ThreadName=main] [timeMillis: 1377099543503] [levelValue: 800] [[
  Grizzly Framework 2.3.1 started in: 3ms - bound to [/0.0.0.0:8,181]]]

[2013-08-21T21:09:03.516+0530] [glassfish 4.0] [INFO] [] [javax.enterprise.system.core] [tid: _ThreadID=1 _ThreadName=main] [timeMillis: 1377099543516] [levelValue: 800] [[
  Grizzly Framework 2.3.1 started in: 3ms - bound to [/0.0.0.0:4,848]]]

[2013-08-21T21:09:03.631+0530] [glassfish 4.0] [INFO] [] [javax.enterprise.system.core.security.org.glassfish.security.services.impl.authorization] [tid: _ThreadID=1 _ThreadName=main] [timeMillis: 1377099543631] [levelValue: 800] [[
  Authorization Service has successfully initialized.]]

[2013-08-21T21:09:03.709+0530] [glassfish 4.0] [INFO] [] [javax.enterprise.system.core] [tid: _ThreadID=1 _ThreadName=main] [timeMillis: 1377099543709] [levelValue: 800] [[
  Grizzly Framework 2.3.1 started in: 2ms - bound to [/0.0.0.0:3,700]]]

[2013-08-21T21:09:03.719+0530] [glassfish 4.0] [INFO] [] [org.glassfish.ha.store.spi.BackingStoreFactoryRegistry] [tid: _ThreadID=1 _ThreadName=main] [timeMillis: 1377099543719] [levelValue: 800] [[
  Registered org.glassfish.ha.store.adapter.cache.ShoalBackingStoreProxy for persistence-type = replicated in BackingStoreFactoryRegistry]]

[2013-08-21T21:09:03.992+0530] [glassfish 4.0] [INFO] [] [org.hibernate.validator.internal.util.Version] [tid: _ThreadID=53 _ThreadName=pool-6-thread-2] [timeMillis: 1377099543992] [levelValue: 800] [[
  HV000001: Hibernate Validator 5.0.0.Final]]

[2013-08-21T21:09:03.992+0530] [glassfish 4.0] [INFO] [NCLS-CORE-00017] [javax.enterprise.system.core] [tid: _ThreadID=1 _ThreadName=main] [timeMillis: 1377099543992] [levelValue: 800] [[
  GlassFish Server Open Source Edition  4.0  (89) startup time : Felix (3,785ms), startup services(1,359ms), total(5,144ms)]]

[2013-08-21T21:09:04.239+0530] [glassfish 4.0] [INFO] [] [org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler] [tid: _ThreadID=52 _ThreadName=pool-6-thread-1] [timeMillis: 1377099544239] [levelValue: 800] [[
  Initiating Jersey application, version Jersey: 2.0 2013-05-03 14:50:15...]]

[2013-08-21T21:09:05.470+0530] [glassfish 4.0] [INFO] [NCLS-JMX-00005] [javax.enterprise.system.jmx] [tid: _ThreadID=54 _ThreadName=Thread-6] [timeMillis: 1377099545470] [levelValue: 800] [[
  JMXStartupService has started JMXConnector on JMXService URL service:jmx:rmi://RAJESHWARAN-MOBI.TOSHIBA-TSIP.COM:8686/jndi/rmi://RAJESHWARAN-MOBI.TOSHIBA-TSIP.COM:8686/jmxrmi]]

[2013-08-21T21:09:05.501+0530] [glassfish 4.0] [INFO] [] [javax.enterprise.system.core] [tid: _ThreadID=1 _ThreadName=main] [timeMillis: 1377099545501] [levelValue: 800] [[
  Grizzly Framework 2.3.1 started in: 43ms - bound to [/0.0.0.0:7,676]]]

[2013-08-21T21:09:05.810+0530] [glassfish 4.0] [INFO] [NCLS-BOOTSTRAP-00027] [javax.enterprise.bootstrap] [tid: _ThreadID=1 _ThreadName=main] [timeMillis: 1377099545810] [levelValue: 800] [[
  Registered com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.osgi.EmbeddedOSGiGlassFishImpl@739168d7 as OSGi service registration: org.apache.felix.framework.ServiceRegistrationImpl@62c7f808.]]

[2013-08-21T21:09:05.857+0530] [glassfish 4.0] [INFO] [] [] [tid: _ThreadID=72 _ThreadName=Thread-10] [timeMillis: 1377099545857] [levelValue: 800] [[
  this.makeModuleFor(org.glassfish.main.web.glue, null) returned OSGiModuleImpl:: Bundle = [org.glassfish.main.web.glue [350]], State = [READY]]]

[2013-08-21T21:09:05.857+0530] [glassfish 4.0] [INFO] [] [] [tid: _ThreadID=72 _ThreadName=Thread-10] [timeMillis: 1377099545857] [levelValue: 800] [[
  this.makeModuleFor(org.glassfish.web.javax.servlet.jsp, null) returned OSGiModuleImpl:: Bundle = [org.glassfish.web.javax.servlet.jsp [209]], State = [READY]]]

[2013-08-21T21:09:06.610+0530] [glassfish 4.0] [INFO] [] [javax.enterprise.system.tools.deployment.common] [tid: _ThreadID=72 _ThreadName=Thread-10] [timeMillis: 1377099546610] [levelValue: 800] [[
  visiting unvisited references]]

[2013-08-21T21:09:06.865+0530] [glassfish 4.0] [INFO] [] [] [tid: _ThreadID=72 _ThreadName=Thread-10] [timeMillis: 1377099546865] [levelValue: 800] [[
  this.makeModuleFor(org.glassfish.main.admingui.console-common, 4.0.0) returned OSGiModuleImpl:: Bundle = [org.glassfish.main.admingui.console-common [76]], State = [READY]]]

[2013-08-21T21:09:06.867+0530] [glassfish 4.0] [INFO] [] [] [tid: _ThreadID=72 _ThreadName=Thread-10] [timeMillis: 1377099546867] [levelValue: 800] [[
  this.makeModuleFor(org.glassfish.hk2.hk2, 2.1.92) returned OSGiModuleImpl:: Bundle = [org.glassfish.hk2.hk2 [176]], State = [READY]]]

[2013-08-21T21:09:06.868+0530] [glassfish 4.0] [INFO] [] [] [tid: _ThreadID=72 _ThreadName=Thread-10] [timeMillis: 1377099546868] [levelValue: 800] [[
  this.makeModuleFor(org.glassfish.main.admingui.console-plugin-service, 4.0.0) returned OSGiModuleImpl:: Bundle = [org.glassfish.main.admingui.console-plugin-service [96]], State = [READY]]]

[2013-08-21T21:09:06.875+0530] [glassfish 4.0] [INFO] [] [] [tid: _ThreadID=72 _ThreadName=Thread-10] [timeMillis: 1377099546875] [levelValue: 800] [[
  this.makeModuleFor(org.glassfish.main.deployment.deployment-client, 4.0.0) returned OSGiModuleImpl:: Bundle = [org.glassfish.main.deployment.deployment-client [111]], State = [READY]]]

[2013-08-21T21:09:06.875+0530] [glassfish 4.0] [INFO] [] [] [tid: _ThreadID=72 _ThreadName=Thread-10] [timeMillis: 1377099546875] [levelValue: 800] [[
  this.makeModuleFor(org.glassfish.main.registration.registration-api, 4.0.0) returned OSGiModuleImpl:: Bundle = [org.glassfish.main.registration.registration-api [305]], State = [READY]]]

[2013-08-21T21:09:06.876+0530] [glassfish 4.0] [INFO] [] [] [tid: _ThreadID=72 _ThreadName=Thread-10] [timeMillis: 1377099546876] [levelValue: 800] [[
  this.makeModuleFor(org.glassfish.main.registration.registration-impl, 4.0.0) returned OSGiModuleImpl:: Bundle = [org.glassfish.main.registration.registration-impl [307]], State = [READY]]]

[2013-08-21T21:09:06.877+0530] [glassfish 4.0] [INFO] [] [] [tid: _ThreadID=72 _ThreadName=Thread-10] [timeMillis: 1377099546877] [levelValue: 800] [[
  this.makeModuleFor(javax.servlet-api, 3.1.0) returned OSGiModuleImpl:: Bundle = [javax.servlet-api [207]], State = [READY]]]

[2013-08-21T21:09:06.877+0530] [glassfish 4.0] [INFO] [] [] [tid: _ThreadID=72 _ThreadName=Thread-10] [timeMillis: 1377099546877] [levelValue: 800] [[
  this.makeModuleFor(javax.servlet.jsp-api, 2.3.1) returned OSGiModuleImpl:: Bundle = [javax.servlet.jsp-api [208]], State = [READY]]]

[2013-08-21T21:09:06.878+0530] [glassfish 4.0] [INFO] [] [] [tid: _ThreadID=72 _ThreadName=Thread-10] [timeMillis: 1377099546878] [levelValue: 800] [[
  this.makeModuleFor(com.sun.el.javax.el, 3.0.0) returned OSGiModuleImpl:: Bundle = [com.sun.el.javax.el [192]], State = [READY]]]

[2013-08-21T21:09:06.878+0530] [glassfish 4.0] [INFO] [] [] [tid: _ThreadID=72 _ThreadName=Thread-10] [timeMillis: 1377099546878] [levelValue: 800] [[
  this.makeModuleFor(com.sun.jsftemplating, 2.1.0) returned OSGiModuleImpl:: Bundle = [com.sun.jsftemplating [252]], State = [READY]]]

[2013-08-21T21:09:06.879+0530] [glassfish 4.0] [INFO] [] [] [tid: _ThreadID=72 _ThreadName=Thread-10] [timeMillis: 1377099546879] [levelValue: 800] [[
  this.makeModuleFor(org.glassfish.main.admingui.dataprovider, 4.0.0) returned OSGiModuleImpl:: Bundle = [org.glassfish.main.admingui.dataprovider [104]], State = [READY]]]

[2013-08-21T21:09:06.879+0530] [glassfish 4.0] [INFO] [] [] [tid: _ThreadID=72 _ThreadName=Thread-10] [timeMillis: 1377099546879] [levelValue: 800] [[
  this.makeModuleFor(com.sun.pkg.client, 1.0.0) returned OSGiModuleImpl:: Bundle = [com.sun.pkg.client [304]], State = [READY]]]

[2013-08-21T21:09:06.879+0530] [glassfish 4.0] [INFO] [] [] [tid: _ThreadID=72 _ThreadName=Thread-10] [timeMillis: 1377099546879] [levelValue: 800] [[
  this.makeModuleFor(org.glassfish.main.admingui.console-jca-plugin, 4.0.0) returned OSGiModuleImpl:: Bundle = [org.glassfish.main.admingui.console-jca-plugin [89]], State = [READY]]]

[2013-08-21T21:09:06.880+0530] [glassfish 4.0] [INFO] [] [] [tid: _ThreadID=72 _ThreadName=Thread-10] [timeMillis: 1377099546880] [levelValue: 800] [[
  this.makeModuleFor(org.glassfish.main.admingui.console-web-plugin, 4.0.0) returned OSGiModuleImpl:: Bundle = [org.glassfish.main.admingui.console-web-plugin [100]], State = [READY]]]

[2013-08-21T21:09:06.880+0530] [glassfish 4.0] [INFO] [] [] [tid: _ThreadID=72 _ThreadName=Thread-10] [timeMillis: 1377099546880] [levelValue: 800] [[
  this.makeModuleFor(org.glassfish.main.admingui.console-corba-plugin, 4.0.0) returned OSGiModuleImpl:: Bundle = [org.glassfish.main.admingui.console-corba-plugin [82]], State = [READY]]]

[2013-08-21T21:09:06.880+0530] [glassfish 4.0] [INFO] [] [] [tid: _ThreadID=72 _ThreadName=Thread-10] [timeMillis: 1377099546880] [levelValue: 800] [[
  this.makeModuleFor(org.glassfish.main.admingui.console-community-branding-plugin, 4.0.0) returned OSGiModuleImpl:: Bundle = [org.glassfish.main.admingui.console-community-branding-plugin [78]], State = [READY]]]

[2013-08-21T21:09:06.881+0530] [glassfish 4.0] [INFO] [] [] [tid: _ThreadID=72 _ThreadName=Thread-10] [timeMillis: 1377099546881] [levelValue: 800] [[
  this.makeModuleFor(org.glassfish.main.admingui.console-jts-plugin, 4.0.0) returned OSGiModuleImpl:: Bundle = [org.glassfish.main.admingui.console-jts-plugin [95]], State = [READY]]]

[2013-08-21T21:09:06.881+0530] [glassfish 4.0] [INFO] [] [] [tid: _ThreadID=72 _ThreadName=Thread-10] [timeMillis: 1377099546881] [levelValue: 800] [[
  this.makeModuleFor(org.glassfish.main.admingui.console-ejb-plugin, 4.0.0) returned OSGiModuleImpl:: Bundle = [org.glassfish.main.admingui.console-ejb-plugin [87]], State = [READY]]]

[2013-08-21T21:09:06.881+0530] [glassfish 4.0] [INFO] [] [] [tid: _ThreadID=72 _ThreadName=Thread-10] [timeMillis: 1377099546881] [levelValue: 800] [[
  this.makeModuleFor(org.glassfish.main.admingui.console-common-full-plugin, 4.0.0) returned OSGiModuleImpl:: Bundle = [org.glassfish.main.admingui.console-common-full-plugin [74]], State = [READY]]]

[2013-08-21T21:09:06.882+0530] [glassfish 4.0] [INFO] [] [] [tid: _ThreadID=72 _ThreadName=Thread-10] [timeMillis: 1377099546882] [levelValue: 800] [[
  this.makeModuleFor(org.glassfish.main.admingui.console-concurrent-plugin, 4.0.0) returned OSGiModuleImpl:: Bundle = [org.glassfish.main.admingui.console-concurrent-plugin [80]], State = [READY]]]

[2013-08-21T21:09:06.882+0530] [glassfish 4.0] [INFO] [] [] [tid: _ThreadID=72 _ThreadName=Thread-10] [timeMillis: 1377099546882] [levelValue: 800] [[
  this.makeModuleFor(org.glassfish.main.admingui.console-common, 4.0.0) returned OSGiModuleImpl:: Bundle = [org.glassfish.main.admingui.console-common [76]], State = [READY]]]

[2013-08-21T21:09:06.882+0530] [glassfish 4.0] [INFO] [] [] [tid: _ThreadID=72 _ThreadName=Thread-10] [timeMillis: 1377099546882] [levelValue: 800] [[
  this.makeModuleFor(org.glassfish.main.admingui.console-jms-plugin, 4.0.0) returned OSGiModuleImpl:: Bundle = [org.glassfish.main.admingui.console-jms-plugin [93]], State = [READY]]]

[2013-08-21T21:09:06.883+0530] [glassfish 4.0] [INFO] [] [] [tid: _ThreadID=72 _ThreadName=Thread-10] [timeMillis: 1377099546883] [levelValue: 800] [[
  this.makeModuleFor(org.glassfish.main.admingui.console-cluster-plugin, 4.0.0) returned OSGiModuleImpl:: Bundle = [org.glassfish.main.admingui.console-cluster-plugin [72]], State = [READY]]]

[2013-08-21T21:09:06.883+0530] [glassfish 4.0] [INFO] [] [] [tid: _ThreadID=72 _ThreadName=Thread-10] [timeMillis: 1377099546883] [levelValue: 800] [[
  this.makeModuleFor(org.glassfish.main.admingui.console-ejb-lite-plugin, 4.0.0) returned OSGiModuleImpl:: Bundle = [org.glassfish.main.admingui.console-ejb-lite-plugin [85]], State = [READY]]]

[2013-08-21T21:09:06.884+0530] [glassfish 4.0] [INFO] [] [] [tid: _ThreadID=72 _ThreadName=Thread-10] [timeMillis: 1377099546884] [levelValue: 800] [[
  this.makeModuleFor(org.glassfish.main.admingui.console-updatecenter-plugin, 4.0.0) returned OSGiModuleImpl:: Bundle = [org.glassfish.main.admingui.console-updatecenter-plugin [98]], State = [READY]]]

[2013-08-21T21:09:06.884+0530] [glassfish 4.0] [INFO] [] [] [tid: _ThreadID=72 _ThreadName=Thread-10] [timeMillis: 1377099546884] [levelValue: 800] [[
  this.makeModuleFor(org.glassfish.main.admingui.console-jdbc-plugin, 4.0.0) returned OSGiModuleImpl:: Bundle = [org.glassfish.main.admingui.console-jdbc-plugin [91]], State = [READY]]]

[2013-08-21T21:09:07.475+0530] [glassfish 4.0] [INFO] [AS-WEB-GLUE-00198] [javax.enterprise.web] [tid: _ThreadID=72 _ThreadName=Thread-10] [timeMillis: 1377099547475] [levelValue: 800] [[
  Created HTTP listener http-listener-1 on host/port 0.0.0.0:8080]]

[2013-08-21T21:09:07.493+0530] [glassfish 4.0] [INFO] [AS-WEB-GLUE-00198] [javax.enterprise.web] [tid: _ThreadID=72 _ThreadName=Thread-10] [timeMillis: 1377099547493] [levelValue: 800] [[
  Created HTTP listener http-listener-2 on host/port 0.0.0.0:8181]]

[2013-08-21T21:09:07.502+0530] [glassfish 4.0] [INFO] [AS-WEB-GLUE-00198] [javax.enterprise.web] [tid: _ThreadID=72 _ThreadName=Thread-10] [timeMillis: 1377099547502] [levelValue: 800] [[
  Created HTTP listener admin-listener on host/port 0.0.0.0:4848]]

[2013-08-21T21:09:07.563+0530] [glassfish 4.0] [INFO] [AS-WEB-GLUE-00200] [javax.enterprise.web] [tid: _ThreadID=72 _ThreadName=Thread-10] [timeMillis: 1377099547563] [levelValue: 800] [[
  Created virtual server server]]

[2013-08-21T21:09:07.563+0530] [glassfish 4.0] [INFO] [AS-WEB-GLUE-00200] [javax.enterprise.web] [tid: _ThreadID=72 _ThreadName=Thread-10] [timeMillis: 1377099547563] [levelValue: 800] [[
  Created virtual server __asadmin]]

[2013-08-21T21:09:07.875+0530] [glassfish 4.0] [INFO] [AS-WEB-CORE-00306] [javax.enterprise.web.core] [tid: _ThreadID=72 _ThreadName=Thread-10] [timeMillis: 1377099547875] [levelValue: 800] [[
  Setting JAAS app name glassfish-web]]

[2013-08-21T21:09:07.875+0530] [glassfish 4.0] [INFO] [AS-WEB-GLUE-00201] [javax.enterprise.web] [tid: _ThreadID=72 _ThreadName=Thread-10] [timeMillis: 1377099547875] [levelValue: 800] [[
  Virtual server server loaded default web module ]]
```

Is it required to run Netbeans 7.4 in Administrator mode? (I have tried but the same error has received).

Please help me to run Glassfish 4 using Netbeans 7.4

Answer (score 23):

For some reason they have added randomly generated passwords to both the webservers installed with Netbeans 7.4 (currently Apache Tomcat 7.0.41.0 and GlassFishServer 4.0).

To find out what these passwords are:

1. Click on the *Services* tab.
2. Expand the *Servers* drop down node (if not already expanded).
3. Right click the web server you want the password for > select *Properties*.
4. In the dialogue window which opens there is a *Password* field, to the right a *show* button click *show* and you have your answer.

In one way it's kind of nice that that there are good passwords out of the box and so it takes care of external access issues right away. But it certainly was annoying figuring this out.

*Here down is information for shell and gui-less concerns, no need to read further if above solved your issues.*

---

**Update**: It turns out that this password is pulled from a text file, on my system this file is found at *~/glassfish-4.0/glassfish/domains/domain1/config/local-password*

**Warning: not a good idea, to manually update that file! (See Update 2)**

The later is good if you're going to administer glassfish from the terminal.

**Update 2**: In some previous versions it was possible to update the above listed file directly, this will no longer work and will break things. To change the password to a known state on fresh glassfish installation without a gui.

Using Glassfish 4.1 or greater on a clean install execute the following from within the asadmin shell:

Enter: `change-admin-password`
Now enter "admin" (the default) twice.
Now enter a new non blank password twice.
Enter: `enable-secure-admin`

With the above done, you can remotely log in from a different host. 
This setup is fine for development needs but for production needs please see glassfish documentation for further security constraints (how to restrict to a port of particular domain).

PS: If you did break the password file by editing it, because it is a new install, simply unzip the glassfish again and copy that file over it self.

Comment: I had the same thing. But while the server was running, I went to properties and manually changed random password with "adminadmin". Since, then my server won't start. I get dialog boxes "GlassFish Server 4.0 failed to start, maybe something else is running ... " and all that rubbish. I also get warnings like "Authorization failed while checking Glassfish Server status. please provide valid administrative credentials"

Answer (score 7):

I opened Services > Servers > GlassFish Server 4.0 > Properties.
Then remove user and password (totally blank)
Suddenly it worked?

Answer (score 5):

You can try to remove the server from NetBeans (tab Services->Servers->GlassFish, right click and remove) and add it again (right click on Servers-> Add server) and in the Add Server dialog, select GlassFish and register some new domain (e.g. domain2) and finish wizard.

Answer (score 2):

Click on the Services -> Server -> Glassfis Server -> Properties

In the dialogue window you see username password fields. Clear password field and it suddenly starts working !

Comment: This trick worked for my fresh glassfish 4.1.1 installation with Netbeans 8.2 on Win7 64

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same error (in Netbeans 7.4 and GlassFish 4) and this came from a wrong login / password, even if I really thought they were correct.
Try resetting them: in the "services" tab, in the list of servers, right click on GlassFish 4 and enter a new login and password.

Comment: There is no option to enter new login and password, we have to enter the existing user name and password, please correct me, if I am misunderstood.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue today, turned out that I had two instances of glassfish installed, one that was installed with the Java EE installer and another from the NetBeans IDE installer

```
drwxrwxr-x. 13 nikhil nikhil 4.0K Jan 25 09:01 glassfish4
drwxrwxr-x.  8 nikhil nikhil 4.0K Jan 25 10:26 glassfish-4.0
```

I'm not quite sure why the default password (admin) wouldn't work from NetBeans, maybe the system couldnt tell the two glassfish servers apart as they were both using default ports. Anyway I manually removed the GlassFish server from NetBeans and added the one that came with the Java EE installer (the one with the correct password), now it works.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem. And I solved it using a small trick. I removed the server installed with NetBeans from the interface and the added another. When you do this you may create a personal domain. And in this personal domain the anonymouns login is already enabled, with no password at all.

I know this is not a good solution, but it is a solution nonetheless.

Hope it helps!

PS: At least in my NwetBeans 7.4 for Linux, sometimes when I leave NetBeans the servers won't go down. Then you have to kill their processes, or else you won't manage to install another due to port conflicts. It's a tricky thing to find the process of the server. When you use "ps -A" the name of the process is only "java", with no clue it is the server.

Answer (score 0):

You can find the default password on the file local-password

On Windows it is at
\AppData\Roaming\NetBeans\7.4\config\GF_4.0\domain1\config

On Linuix is should be something like
.netbeans.....

Answer (score 0):

Click on the Services -> Server -> Glassfis Server -> Properties

In the dialogue window you see user name=admin  and password=admin. Clear password field.

Answer (score 0):

Bug 234594 - Cannot use previously installed GlassFish due to missing password

https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=234594

Answer (score 0):

find this File:
...glassfish\domains\domain1\config\local-password
read and type the password

Comment: I had the same problem and this was the solution!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, this is for **Netbeams 8.2** and **Glassfish 4.1.1.**
Go to `Tools > Servers` and remove the GlassFish Server. Then proceed
to download Glassfish using this page https://javaee.github.io/glassfish/download
Create a folder under **C:\User\YourUser**. Name the Folder `Glassfish_Server` and put the Zip file in it. On NetBeans select the Add Server and select GlassFish Server use the browse option to select the folder where the Zip file is located (the one created on C:\User) select Next and wait for it to complete. This should bypass the Bug in NetBeans 8.2 and GlassFish 4.1.1 to fix the `Please check server admin user name and password properties.` error.

Answer (score -1):

Just update NB (`Tools > Plugins > Updates`). I had the same problem. So, I updated my NB, and then, the problem was gone.