# I cannot open my GlassFish admin panel it demands user name and password

Tags: netbeans, console, glassfish, admin

I'm trying to reach my GlassFish 4.0 console, which is at localhost 4848. I start my GlassFish server from my NetBeans, then I go my port. It starts itself and then it asks me for a password and username. But the problem is that I have just downloaded and run that and I haven't authenticated any password and user and I can't open my GlassFish server admin panel.

Answer (score 1):

if you downloaded your AS instance from Oracle web site(separately from NetBeans)

https://glassfish.java.net/download.html

and start domain from console with

```
asadmin start-domain domain1
```

you would not have any troubles with authentication. However it looks like NetBeans puzzles you. You may find a solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18362037/glassfish-4-admin-not-running-from-netbeans-7-4-password-incorrect). See Quaternion's answer.