# glassfish-4 start failed after upgrade Mac OS Sierra

Tags: macos, netbeans, glassfish

I already upgraded to MacOS Sierra and my Netbeans 8.0.2 throw an error when I try to run Glassfish.

> Please check server admin user name and password properties.
>
> Also please check the server log file for other possible causes.

I tried all posibles solutions that I found in stackoverflow but nothing worked.

[Glassfish 4 Admin not running from Netbeans 7.4 (Password Incorrect)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18362037/glassfish-4-admin-not-running-from-netbeans-7-4-password-incorrect)

This is the log of Glassfish

```html
objc[35340]: Class JavaLaunchHelper is implemented in both /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_91.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java (0x1000a54c0) and /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_91.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/libinstrument.dylib (0x1001b84e0). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
Listening for transport dt_socket at address: 9009
Launching GlassFish on Felix platform
Nov 02, 2016 11:28:52 AM com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.osgi.BundleProvisioner createBundleProvisioner
INFO: Create bundle provisioner class = class com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.osgi.BundleProvisioner.
Nov 02, 2016 11:28:53 AM com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.osgi.BundleProvisioner$DefaultCustomizer getLocations
WARNING: Skipping entry  because it is not an absolute URI.
Nov 02, 2016 11:28:53 AM com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.osgi.BundleProvisioner$DefaultCustomizer getLocations
WARNING: Skipping entry  because it is not an absolute URI.
Registered com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.osgi.EmbeddedOSGiGlassFishRuntime@c76ff05 in service registry.
Found populator: com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.GFDomainXml
#!## LogManagerService.postConstruct : rootFolder=/Applications/NetBeans/glassfish-4.1/glassfish
#!## LogManagerService.postConstruct : templateDir=/Applications/NetBeans/glassfish-4.1/glassfish/lib/templates
#!## LogManagerService.postConstruct : src=/Applications/NetBeans/glassfish-4.1/glassfish/lib/templates/logging.properties
#!## LogManagerService.postConstruct : dest=/Applications/NetBeans/glassfish-4.1/glassfish/domains/domain4/config/logging.properties
Info:   Running GlassFish Version: GlassFish Server Open Source Edition  4.1  (build 13)
Info:   Server log file is using Formatter class: com.sun.enterprise.server.logging.ODLLogFormatter
Info:   Realm [admin-realm] of classtype [com.sun.enterprise.security.auth.realm.file.FileRealm] successfully created.
Info:   Realm [file] of classtype [com.sun.enterprise.security.auth.realm.file.FileRealm] successfully created.
Info:   Realm [certificate] of classtype [com.sun.enterprise.security.auth.realm.certificate.CertificateRealm] successfully created.
Info:   Authorization Service has successfully initialized.
Info:   Registered org.glassfish.ha.store.adapter.cache.ShoalBackingStoreProxy for persistence-type = replicated in BackingStoreFactoryRegistry
Info:   Grizzly Framework 2.3.15 started in: 58ms - bound to [/0.0.0.0:9090]
Info:   Grizzly Framework 2.3.15 started in: 12ms - bound to [/0.0.0.0:9191]
Info:   Grizzly Framework 2.3.15 started in: 2ms - bound to [/0.0.0.0:4848]
Info:   Grizzly Framework 2.3.15 started in: 1ms - bound to [/0.0.0.0:3700]
Info:   GlassFish Server Open Source Edition  4.1  (13) startup time : Felix (37,175ms), startup services(1,405ms), total(38,580ms)
Info:   Creating a SecureRMIServerSocketFactory @ 0.0.0.0 with ssl config = GlassFishConfigBean.org.glassfish.grizzly.config.dom.Ssl
Info:   SSLParams =org.glassfish.admin.mbeanserver.ssl.SSLParams@5baca86
Warning:   All SSL cipher suites disabled for network-listener(s).  Using SSL implementation specific defaults
Info:   SSLParams =org.glassfish.admin.mbeanserver.ssl.SSLParams@5baca86
Warning:   All SSL cipher suites disabled for network-listener(s).  Using SSL implementation specific defaults
Info:   Grizzly Framework 2.3.15 started in: 11ms - bound to [/0.0.0.0:7676]
Info:   Registered com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.osgi.EmbeddedOSGiGlassFishImpl@3baf6936 as OSGi service registration: org.apache.felix.framework.ServiceRegistrationImpl@4acb2510.
Info:   visiting unvisited references
Info:   Created HTTP listener http-listener-1 on host/port 0.0.0.0:9090
Info:   Created HTTP listener http-listener-2 on host/port 0.0.0.0:9191
Info:   Created HTTP listener admin-listener on host/port 0.0.0.0:4848
Info:   Created virtual server server
Info:   Created virtual server __asadmin
Info:   Setting JAAS app name glassfish-web
Info:   Virtual server server loaded default web module 
Info:   Java security manager is disabled.
Info:   Entering Security Startup Service.
Info:   Loading policy provider com.sun.enterprise.security.provider.PolicyWrapper.
Info:   Security Service(s) started successfully.
Info:   visiting unvisited references
Info:   visiting unvisited references
Info:   visiting unvisited references
Info:   Initializing Mojarra 2.2.7 ( 20140610-1547 https://svn.java.net/svn/mojarra~svn/tags/2.2.7@13362) for context ''
Info:   HV000001: Hibernate Validator 5.0.0.Final
Info:   SSLServerSocket /0.0.0.0:8686 and [SSL: ServerSocket[addr=/0.0.0.0,localport=8686]] created
Info:   Loading application [__admingui] at [/]
Info:   Loading application __admingui done in 15,743 ms
Info:   JMXStartupService has started JMXConnector on JMXService URL service:jmx:rmi://10.57.116.239:8686/jndi/rmi://10.57.116.239:8686/jmxrmi
```

I don't know what else to do.

Please help me with this problem.

Comment: The log shows that GlassFish has started correctly. The start hasn't failed, but your login has. What user name and password have you set?

Comment: I tried all... login admin and the empty pass. Login anonymous and the password from glassfish/domains/domain1/config/local-password.  I also changed the password from Admin but never worked. In my other macbook with El capitan OS works perfectly.

Answer (score -1):

you can set system java version,and this can do by jenv;please reference
http://boxingp.github.io/blog/2015/01/25/manage-multiple-versions-of-java-on-os-x/