# GlassFish Deployment Error on NetBeans

Tags: java, netbeans, glassfish

I am getting the error below when deploying a web application using **Glassfish 4.1** using **Netbeans 8.2**

> Starting GlassFish Server 4.1.1
>   GlassFish Server 4.1.1 start failed
> Please check server admin username and password properties.
> Also please check the server log file for other possible causes.
>   /Users/suraaz/TestApp/nbproject/build-impl.xml:1046: Deployment error: GlassFish Server 4.1.1 start failed
> Please check server admin user name and password properties.
> Also please check the server log file for other possible causes.
>   See the server log for details.
>   BUILD FAILED (total time: 6 minutes 24 seconds)

We have tried looking for solutions but still no luck. We are using it on a mac. Suggestions will be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Glassfish 4 Admin not running from Netbeans 7.4 (Password Incorrect)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18362037/glassfish-4-admin-not-running-from-netbeans-7-4-password-incorrect)

Comment: As the message says: See the server log for details.

Answer (score 2):

Was a simple fix. This error is normally with mac OS Sierra.
Go to Network Preferences, click on your Internet connection - Goto Advanced - Proxies - Make sure Auto Proxy Discovery is selected. Also select Automatic Proxy Configuration and Web Proxy if that doesn't work. 
Cheers

Comment: Surprisingly, this solution worked for me. I'm running NetBeans 8.2 with GlassFish 4.1.1 on macOS Sierra 10.12.5.