# GlassFish Server 4.1.1 start failed, what i can do?

Tags: jsp, jakarta-ee, glassfish-4.1, netbeans-8.2

GlassFish Server 4.1.1 start failed
Please check server admin user name and password properties.
Also please check the server log file for other possible causes.

Comment: when i try to run the web application,it shows above error

Comment: Have you looked in any logs for more information?

Comment: no it shows only above words

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Glassfish 4 Admin not running from Netbeans 7.4 (Password Incorrect)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18362037/glassfish-4-admin-not-running-from-netbeans-7-4-password-incorrect)

Comment: Have a look at that link and see if it helps - if its totally off I'll removed the "Possible Duplicate" piece.  Let us know if it helps!