# Glassfish server start failed

Tags: netbeans, glassfish

I have created a project in netbeans ide, when I run the project a dialogue box comes with the title "information" and message "glassfish server start failed please check server admin user name and password properties also please check the server log file for other possible causes". I did not set any username or password for the glassfish server. When I open C:\Users\Robert Mdee\glassfish6\glassfish\domains\domain1\logs I find the server text document with the code

```
[2022-08-09T23:05:31.163+0300] [] [INFO] [NCLS-GFLAUNCHER-00005] [jakarta.enterprise.launcher] [tid: _ThreadID=1 _ThreadName=main] [timeMillis: 1660075531163] [levelValue: 800] [[
  JVM invocation command line:
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-18.0.1.1\bin\java.exe
-cp
C:/Users/Robert Mdee/glassfish6/glassfish/modules/glassfish.jar
-XX:+UnlockDiagnosticVMOptions
-XX:NewRatio=2
-Xmx512m
-Xbootclasspath/a:C:\Users\Robert Mdee\glassfish6\glassfish/lib/grizzly-npn-api.jar
--add-opens=jdk.management/com.sun.management.internal=ALL-UNNAMED
--add-opens=java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.jrt=ALL-UNNAMED
--add-opens=java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED
--add-opens=java.base/java.util=ALL-UNNAMED
--add-opens=java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport=ALL-UNNAMED
-javaagent:C:/Users/Robert Mdee/glassfish6/glassfish/lib/monitor/flashlight-agent.jar
-Djava.awt.headless=true
-Djdk.corba.allowOutputStreamSubclass=true
-Djdk.tls.rejectClientInitiatedRenegotiation=true
-Djavax.xml.accessExternalSchema=all
-Djava.security.policy=C:\Users\Robert Mdee\glassfish6\glassfish\domains\domain1/config/server.policy
-Djava.security.auth.login.config=C:\Users\Robert Mdee\glassfish6\glassfish\domains\domain1/config/login.conf
-Dcom.sun.enterprise.security.httpsOutboundKeyAlias=s1as
-Djavax.net.ssl.keyStore=C:\Users\Robert Mdee\glassfish6\glassfish\domains\domain1/config/keystore.jks
-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=C:\Users\Robert Mdee\glassfish6\glassfish\domains\domain1/config/cacerts.jks
-Djdbc.drivers=org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver
-DANTLR_USE_DIRECT_CLASS_LOADING=true
-Dcom.sun.enterprise.config.config_environment_factory_class=com.sun.enterprise.config.serverbeans.AppserverConfigEnvironmentFactory
-Dorg.glassfish.additionalOSGiBundlesToStart=org.apache.felix.shell,org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime,org.apache.felix.gogo.shell,org.apache.felix.gogo.command,org.apache.felix.shell.remote,org.apache.felix.fileinstall
-Dosgi.shell.telnet.port=6666
-Dosgi.shell.telnet.maxconn=1
-Dosgi.shell.telnet.ip=127.0.0.1
-Dgosh.args=--nointeractive
-Dfelix.fileinstall.dir=C:\Users\Robert Mdee\glassfish6\glassfish/modules/autostart/
-Dfelix.fileinstall.poll=5000
-Dfelix.fileinstall.log.level=2
-Dfelix.fileinstall.bundles.new.start=true
-Dfelix.fileinstall.bundles.startTransient=true
-Dfelix.fileinstall.disableConfigSave=false
-Dorg.glassfish.gmbal.no.multipleUpperBoundsException=true
-Dcom.ctc.wstx.returnNullForDefaultNamespace=true
-Dcom.sun.aas.instanceRoot=C:\Users\Robert Mdee\glassfish6\glassfish\domains\domain1
-Dcom.sun.aas.installRoot=C:\Users\Robert Mdee\glassfish6\glassfish
-Djava.library.path=C:/Users/Robert Mdee/glassfish6/glassfish/lib;C:/Program Files/Java/jdk-18.0.1.1/bin;C:/Windows/Sun/Java/bin;C:/Windows/System32;C:/Windows;C:/Program Files/Java/jdk-17/bin;C:/Program Files/Java/jdk-16.0.2/bin;C:/Program Files/Common Files/Oracle/Java/javapath;C:/Windows/System32/wbem;C:/Windows/System32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0;C:/Windows/System32/OpenSSH;C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/miktex/bin/x64;C:/Program Files/MySQL/MySQL Shell 8.0/bin;C:/Users/Robert Mdee/AppData/Local/Microsoft/WindowsApps;C:/Users/Robert Mdee/glassfish6/glassfish/bin
com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.ASMain
-upgrade
false
-domaindir
C:/Users/Robert Mdee/glassfish6/glassfish/domains/domain1
-read-stdin
true
-asadmin-args
--host,,,localhost,,,--port,,,4848,,,--secure=false,,,--terse=false,,,--echo=false,,,--interactive=true,,,start-domain,,,--verbose=false,,,--watchdog=false,,,--debug=false,,,--domaindir,,,C:\Users\Robert Mdee\glassfish6\glassfish\domains,,,domain1
-domainname
domain1
-instancename
server
-type
DAS
-verbose
false
-asadmin-classpath
C:/Users/Robert Mdee/glassfish6/glassfish/lib/client/appserver-cli.jar
-debug
false
-asadmin-classname
com.sun.enterprise.admin.cli.AdminMain]]

[2022-08-09T23:15:49.174+0300] [] [INFO] [NCLS-GFLAUNCHER-00005] [jakarta.enterprise.launcher] [tid: _ThreadID=1 _ThreadName=main] [timeMillis: 1660076149174] [levelValue: 800] [[
  JVM invocation command line:
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-18.0.1.1\bin\java.exe
-cp
C:/Users/Robert Mdee/glassfish6/glassfish/modules/glassfish.jar
-XX:+UnlockDiagnosticVMOptions
-XX:NewRatio=2
-Xmx512m
-Xbootclasspath/a:C:\Users\Robert Mdee\glassfish6\glassfish/lib/grizzly-npn-api.jar
--add-opens=jdk.management/com.sun.management.internal=ALL-UNNAMED
--add-opens=java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.jrt=ALL-UNNAMED
--add-opens=java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED
--add-opens=java.base/java.util=ALL-UNNAMED
--add-opens=java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport=ALL-UNNAMED
-javaagent:C:/Users/Robert Mdee/glassfish6/glassfish/lib/monitor/flashlight-agent.jar
-Djava.awt.headless=true
-Djdk.corba.allowOutputStreamSubclass=true
-Djdk.tls.rejectClientInitiatedRenegotiation=true
-Djavax.xml.accessExternalSchema=all
-Djava.security.policy=C:\Users\Robert Mdee\glassfish6\glassfish\domains\domain1/config/server.policy
-Djava.security.auth.login.config=C:\Users\Robert Mdee\glassfish6\glassfish\domains\domain1/config/login.conf
-Dcom.sun.enterprise.security.httpsOutboundKeyAlias=s1as
-Djavax.net.ssl.keyStore=C:\Users\Robert Mdee\glassfish6\glassfish\domains\domain1/config/keystore.jks
-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=C:\Users\Robert Mdee\glassfish6\glassfish\domains\domain1/config/cacerts.jks
-Djdbc.drivers=org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver
-DANTLR_USE_DIRECT_CLASS_LOADING=true
-Dcom.sun.enterprise.config.config_environment_factory_class=com.sun.enterprise.config.serverbeans.AppserverConfigEnvironmentFactory
-Dorg.glassfish.additionalOSGiBundlesToStart=org.apache.felix.shell,org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime,org.apache.felix.gogo.shell,org.apache.felix.gogo.command,org.apache.felix.shell.remote,org.apache.felix.fileinstall
-Dosgi.shell.telnet.port=6666
-Dosgi.shell.telnet.maxconn=1
-Dosgi.shell.telnet.ip=127.0.0.1
-Dgosh.args=--nointeractive
-Dfelix.fileinstall.dir=C:\Users\Robert Mdee\glassfish6\glassfish/modules/autostart/
-Dfelix.fileinstall.poll=5000
-Dfelix.fileinstall.log.level=2
-Dfelix.fileinstall.bundles.new.start=true
-Dfelix.fileinstall.bundles.startTransient=true
-Dfelix.fileinstall.disableConfigSave=false
-Dorg.glassfish.gmbal.no.multipleUpperBoundsException=true
-Dcom.ctc.wstx.returnNullForDefaultNamespace=true
-Dcom.sun.aas.instanceRoot=C:\Users\Robert Mdee\glassfish6\glassfish\domains\domain1
-Dcom.sun.aas.installRoot=C:\Users\Robert Mdee\glassfish6\glassfish
-Djava.library.path=C:/Users/Robert Mdee/glassfish6/glassfish/lib;C:/Program Files/Java/jdk-18.0.1.1/bin;C:/Windows/Sun/Java/bin;C:/Windows/System32;C:/Windows;C:/Program Files/Java/jdk-17/bin;C:/Program Files/Java/jdk-16.0.2/bin;C:/Program Files/Common Files/Oracle/Java/javapath;C:/Windows/System32/wbem;C:/Windows/System32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0;C:/Windows/System32/OpenSSH;C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/miktex/bin/x64;C:/Program Files/MySQL/MySQL Shell 8.0/bin;C:/Users/Robert Mdee/AppData/Local/Microsoft/WindowsApps;C:/Users/Robert Mdee/glassfish6/bin
com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.ASMain
-upgrade
false
-domaindir
C:/Users/Robert Mdee/glassfish6/glassfish/domains/domain1
-read-stdin
true
-asadmin-args
--host,,,localhost,,,--port,,,4848,,,--secure=false,,,--terse=false,,,--echo=false,,,--interactive=true,,,start-domain,,,--verbose=false,,,--watchdog=false,,,--debug=false,,,--domaindir,,,C:\Users\Robert Mdee\glassfish6\glassfish\domains,,,domain1
-domainname
domain1
-instancename
server
-type
DAS
-verbose
false
-asadmin-classpath
C:/Users/Robert Mdee/glassfish6/glassfish/lib/client/appserver-cli.jar
-debug
false
-asadmin-classname
com.sun.enterprise.admin.cli.AdminMain]]

[2022-08-09T23:18:16.179+0300] [] [INFO] [NCLS-GFLAUNCHER-00005] [jakarta.enterprise.launcher] [tid: _ThreadID=1 _ThreadName=main] [timeMillis: 1660076296179] [levelValue: 800] [[
  JVM invocation command line:
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-18.0.1.1\bin\java.exe
-cp
C:/Users/Robert Mdee/glassfish6/glassfish/modules/glassfish.jar
-XX:+UnlockDiagnosticVMOptions
-XX:NewRatio=2
-Xmx512m
-Xbootclasspath/a:C:\Users\Robert Mdee\glassfish6\glassfish/lib/grizzly-npn-api.jar
--add-opens=jdk.management/com.sun.management.internal=ALL-UNNAMED
--add-opens=java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.jrt=ALL-UNNAMED
--add-opens=java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED
--add-opens=java.base/java.util=ALL-UNNAMED
--add-opens=java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport=ALL-UNNAMED
-javaagent:C:/Users/Robert Mdee/glassfish6/glassfish/lib/monitor/flashlight-agent.jar
-Djava.awt.headless=true
-Djdk.corba.allowOutputStreamSubclass=true
-Djdk.tls.rejectClientInitiatedRenegotiation=true
-Djavax.xml.accessExternalSchema=all
-Djava.security.policy=C:\Users\Robert Mdee\glassfish6\glassfish\domains\domain1/config/server.policy
-Djava.security.auth.login.config=C:\Users\Robert Mdee\glassfish6\glassfish\domains\domain1/config/login.conf
-Dcom.sun.enterprise.security.httpsOutboundKeyAlias=s1as
-Djavax.net.ssl.keyStore=C:\Users\Robert Mdee\glassfish6\glassfish\domains\domain1/config/keystore.jks
-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=C:\Users\Robert Mdee\glassfish6\glassfish\domains\domain1/config/cacerts.jks
-Djdbc.drivers=org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver
-DANTLR_USE_DIRECT_CLASS_LOADING=true
-Dcom.sun.enterprise.config.config_environment_factory_class=com.sun.enterprise.config.serverbeans.AppserverConfigEnvironmentFactory
-Dorg.glassfish.additionalOSGiBundlesToStart=org.apache.felix.shell,org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime,org.apache.felix.gogo.shell,org.apache.felix.gogo.command,org.apache.felix.shell.remote,org.apache.felix.fileinstall
-Dosgi.shell.telnet.port=6666
-Dosgi.shell.telnet.maxconn=1
-Dosgi.shell.telnet.ip=127.0.0.1
-Dgosh.args=--nointeractive
-Dfelix.fileinstall.dir=C:\Users\Robert Mdee\glassfish6\glassfish/modules/autostart/
-Dfelix.fileinstall.poll=5000
-Dfelix.fileinstall.log.level=2
-Dfelix.fileinstall.bundles.new.start=true
-Dfelix.fileinstall.bundles.startTransient=true
-Dfelix.fileinstall.disableConfigSave=false
-Dorg.glassfish.gmbal.no.multipleUpperBoundsException=true
-Dcom.ctc.wstx.returnNullForDefaultNamespace=true
-Dcom.sun.aas.instanceRoot=C:\Users\Robert Mdee\glassfish6\glassfish\domains\domain1
-Dcom.sun.aas.installRoot=C:\Users\Robert Mdee\glassfish6\glassfish
-Djava.library.path=C:/Users/Robert Mdee/glassfish6/glassfish/lib;C:/Program Files/Java/jdk-18.0.1.1/bin;C:/Windows/Sun/Java/bin;C:/Windows/System32;C:/Windows;C:/Program Files/Java/jdk-17/bin;C:/Program Files/Java/jdk-16.0.2/bin;C:/Program Files/Common Files/Oracle/Java/javapath;C:/Windows/System32/wbem;C:/Windows/System32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0;C:/Windows/System32/OpenSSH;C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/miktex/bin/x64;C:/Program Files/MySQL/MySQL Shell 8.0/bin;C:/Users/Robert Mdee/AppData/Local/Microsoft/WindowsApps;C:/Users/Robert Mdee/glassfish6/bin
com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.ASMain
-upgrade
false
-domaindir
C:/Users/Robert Mdee/glassfish6/glassfish/domains/domain1
-read-stdin
true
-asadmin-args
--host,,,localhost,,,--port,,,4848,,,--secure=false,,,--terse=false,,,--echo=false,,,--interactive=true,,,start-domain,,,--verbose=false,,,--watchdog=false,,,--debug=false,,,--domaindir,,,C:\Users\Robert Mdee\glassfish6\glassfish\domains,,,domain1
-domainname
domain1
-instancename
server
-type
DAS
-verbose
false
-asadmin-classpath
C:/Users/Robert Mdee/glassfish6/glassfish/lib/client/appserver-cli.jar
-debug
false
-asadmin-classname
com.sun.enterprise.admin.cli.AdminMain]]
```

What can I do to correct this error so the project can sucesfully run and open the browser.

Comment: (1) What version of NetBeans are you using? (2) Did you install Glassfish separately, or was it bundled with NetBeans when NetBeans was installed? (3) Take a look at [Glassfish 4 Admin not running from Netbeans 7.4 (Password Incorrect)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18362037/12567365) for possible ways to locate and use the user ID and password. It's an old question, but the advice may still be relevant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't specify your precise version of Glassfish, but based on the directory path  "*...\glassfish6\glassfish...*" in your log I'm assuming that you are running some implementation of GlassFish 6.

If so, these are the supported Java releases for Eclipse GlassFish 6.x:

```
GlassFish 6 requires JDK 8.
GlassFish 6.1 supports JDK 11
GlassFish 6.2.1 supports JDK 17
GlassFish 6.2.2 supports JDK 17
GlassFish 6.2.3 supports JDK 17
GlassFish 6.2.4 supports JDK 18
GlassFish 6.2.5 supports JDK 18
```

See the [Eclipse GlassFish Downloads](https://glassfish.org/download) page for more details.

You also don't specify your version of NetBeans, but since you are running Java 18, your only valid options are [NetBeans 13](https://netbeans.apache.org/download/nb13/nb13.html) or [NetBeans 14](https://netbeans.apache.org/download/nb14/nb14.html).

To summarize, since the log shows that you are using JDK 18:

- You must use GlassFish 6.2.4 or GlassFish 6.2.5.
- You must use NetBeans 13 or NetBeans 14.

Note that the version of Java being used by NetBeans, as shown in the **Help > About** screen, will also be used to run GlassFish when started within NetBeans.

As a possibly related matter, I see that your **java.library.path** value includes entries for several JDK releases. You probably want to clean that up.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the good answer it will help so many, I am using netbeans 14. Though yesterday I decided to end the frustration by using apache tomcat server instead of the glassfish server. No errors this time